# How do i send variables to another php with cURL?

Tags: php, curl

im try to send variable from a php page to anotherone in diffrent server,but it doesnt work.here is my code.witch part of this i did wrong?

```
$Phone='09757527255';
$Random='123456';
$data=array("phone"=>$Phone,"random"=>$Random);
$string=http_build_query($data);
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://xxxxxxx.com/xxxxx.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$string);

// Receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Comment: But it doesnt work for me

Comment: "*doesnt work*" is not helpful. What doesnt work. What errors do you get. What results are happening that are not what you wanted. Be helpful, if you want help.

Comment: how can i say when i doesnt know!!!i check my destination code with GET and manually send data with url and it was fine.and i catch above code is fine too

Comment: What happens with this code? Does the other server receive this? Do you get an error?

Comment: no it doesnt receive.i try to put variable in database with destination code but there is nothing to save.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending curl request with `CURLOPT_POST` set to 1, so you should receive data from $_POST variable. Maybe you are trying to receive it from $_GET variable?